# Google Analytics weird User numbers

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

When I check the website's Users since a certain date it returns a super low value.

The example:

If I want to see the data from 01/01/2016 until 13/06/2021 I get 6 Users, 32.323 New Users,  37.611 Sessions, etc.
The Users number don't make any sense.

However, if I do 01/09/2016 until 13/06/2021 I get 16.849 Users, 16.973 New Users and 22.142 Sessions.
These numbers do make more sense.

So basically, if I consider ANY START DATE before the 01/09/2016 I will always get a super reduced value in the Users part, however, if I consider any start date after, and including, 01/09/2016 I will get reasoable values.

Has anyone ever had this issue?

Answer (score 0):

From **1 September 2016** Google Analytics has brought a new feature, the ability to set the **Users metric** as the main metric, instead of Sessions. This event has taken the name of Users Everywhere and involves some relationships including Audience Reports and Acquisition Reports.

If the date range includes a period of time, even one day only, prior to 1 September 2016 or around that date, the result is like this:

[image]

This is valid, however, if the option to enable the Users metric in the reports , present at the Property level, is active:

[image]

**Note**: Google Analytics Standard properties have aggregated user metrics data since September 1, 2016 while Google Analytics 360 properties started aggregating data from May 1, 2016).

Source: https://www.analyticstraps.com/zero-utenti-con-sessioni/